# Junit Mockito test case for ResponseEntity<?> in spring integration framework

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-integration

I am trying to mock the external call.

```html
 ResponseEntity<?> httpResponse = requestGateway.pushNotification(xtifyRequest);
```

requestGateway is an interface.

```
public interface RequestGateway
{
ResponseEntity<?> pushNotification(XtifyRequest xtifyRequest);
}
```

Below is the test method i am trying to do.

```
 @Test
public void test()
{


    ResponseEntity<?> r=new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

    when(requestGateway.pushNotification(any(XtifyRequest.class))).thenReturn(r);
}
```

A compilation error is there in the above when statement,saying it as an invalid type.even thougg r is of type ResponseEntity.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can instead use the type-unsafe method

```
doReturn(r).when(requestGateway.pushNotification(any(XtifyRequest.class)));
```

Or you can remove the type info while mocking

```
ResponseEntity r=new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
when(requestGateway.pushNotification(any(XtifyRequest.class))).thenReturn(r);
```