# How to mock the ResponseEntity<?> with generic type?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I need to mock a service. i m getting null in `ResponseEntity<?>` resp while mocking the class.

Method which need to mock:

```
public List<Expression> getExpression(String expressView, Localdate date) {

    List<Expression> =new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> uri = new HashMap<>();
    UriComponenetsBuilder build = 
        UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("someUrl" + "/" + expressView);
    build.queryParam(someParameter, someParameter);
    build.queryParam(someParameter, someParameter);
    build.queryParam(someParameter, someParameter);

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    RestClient client = new RestClient(
        build.build().encode.toUriString, HttpMethod.GET.Uri, header
    );

    ResponseEntity<?> resp = restC.SomeMethod(client);

    if (resp = !null) {
        //it goes to these line
    }

  }
```

In my mock method:

```
when(restC.SomeMethod(client)).thenReturn(resp);
```

So above method call a service get some data get the value of expressView and save as list. when i mocked the method `when(restC.SomeMethod(client)).thenReturn(resp);` it hit the URL but the value i m getting as response `resp` is null . 
So here i m getting the `resp` value as `null`. I checked the URL(someUrl) in postman its returning the value.

How to mock the `ResponseEntity<?>`?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Junit Mockito test case for ResponseEntity<?> in spring integration framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015830/junit-mockito-test-case-for-responseentity-in-spring-integration-framework)

Comment: Hi , @J.Macedo i tried this example still getting the null value.

Answer (score 16):

First, create a `ResponseEntity` object:

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(
    "some response body",
    header, 
    HttpStatus.OK
);
```

Then build a mock to return the `responseEntity` object:

```
when(restC.SomeMethod(client)).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

---

Point to pay attention:

> Avoid to use `ResponseEntity` inside `@Service class`. You should use `ResponseEntity` in `@RestController class`.

And you can `Inject` your `@Service class` using `@Autowired` annotation, like:

```
@RestController
public class YourControllerClass {

    @Autowired
    private YourServiceClass yourServiceClass;
```

Or using `constructor`, like:

```
@RestController
public class YourControllerClass {

    private YourServiceClass yourServiceClass;

    public YourControllerClass(YourServiceClass yourServiceClass) {
        this.yourServiceClass= yourServiceClass;
    }
```

So:

> `@Service class` will handle `business or data objects` and `@RestController class` will handle `Response` and `Request` objects. Thus we have `Single Responsibility` principle.

---

Some nice links:

- [Spring MVC - Using RequestEntity and ResponseEntity](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-response-entity.html)
- [How do I mock a REST template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486521/how-do-i-mock-a-rest-template-exchange)
- [Building REST services with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)
- [Understanding the Single Responsibility Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276481/6689024)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I improved my answer with suggestions, examples and some nice links ;) I hope this will help you.